# How to press a key programmatically in a TextField?

Tags: android, libgdx, textfield

I have a `TextField`, and I want to press the switch charset button programmatically. I've tried  this, but I get a **`NullPointerException`**.

```
   myTextfield.addListener(new FocusListener(){
    public void keyboardFocusChanged(FocusEvent event, Actor actor, boolean focused){
        if(focused){
           InputEvent ie = new InputEvent();
           ie.setKeyCode(Keys.SWITCH_CHARSET);
           actor.fire(ie);
        }
    }
   });
```

This is the log cat error

[image]

Comment: Hi agian^^ just a suggestion: Try to add more informations to the question in the libgdx forums. The question there seems a bit strange, if you don't know what it is about.

Comment: Which specific line is the null pointer exception referring to?

Comment: actor.fire(ie). Something is wrong and I don't know what

Comment: Why don't you check the actual code to see what's `null` and then set it?

Comment: I did. But I think something is null in my InputEvent, but I can´t see why :(

Comment: That's why I said, check the *actual code* which throws the nullpointer and see what's `null` in your event. Then set it. If you do that, you will see that you did not set the event **type**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the type of the event. That's what causes the `NullPointerException`, which you can see if you look at the code (LibGDX is neither closed source, nor black magic). Depending on what you actually want to do, you have to choose another type of event, than the one I chose:

```
InputEvent ie = new InputEvent();
ie.setKeyCode(Keys.SWITCH_CHARSET);
ie.setType(Type.keyUp);
actor.fire(ie);
```

Comment: Thanks, you opened my eyes, right now there aren't any erros. But I tried with keyUp, keyDown and keyTyped and my keyboard doesn't change. Does it work for you?

Comment: Um, switching the character set is something that Android would do. Firing this event on an actor won't help you with that...

Comment: Yeah, I know... as android native code is really easy, but this simple issue is delaying me a lot of time... It's a pity that TextField doesnt support default numeric keyboard.

Comment: I think you need to use native android here, see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: Yeah, I gave up. I already implemented the android native edittext and they are working fine. Anyway thank you for your tips =)

Comment: @noone just a question: It seems like it is possible to manually fire key events. But are they handled differently or what is the problem here? Is the onScreenKeyboard handled by android itself? And only the `keyEvents` are sent to libgdx?

Comment: @Springrbua If you create the event with all necessary information, it's not different and will be handled just like "real" events. But the events that libgdx fires to the `InputProcessor` are only one way. It's platform specific code in the backends of libgdx that catch the real operating system specific events, packs them into a libgdx event, and forwards that to the processors. But this is just one-way. Firing the "SWITCH_CHARSET" event on an actor will just result in that event being passed to the `InputProcessors`, but not actually back to the OS (in this case Android).

Comment: Okay so the difference is, that "real" keyevents are handled by the OS, which gives them to libgdx, while "fired" events are handled by libgdx only. Thanks again @noone